# Contact Form 7 Conversion Goals Not Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, contact-form

I am using Universal Analytics and have added the following code under the "Additional Settings" tab as suggested by dozens of articles including the one suggested by Contact Form 7's website:

on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit', 'success');"

My Category, Action, and Labels all match set up in Goals. I have been testing this for hours and using various other methods on a different website but still no joy. I am not using any SEO or Yoast Plugins, and I have the Universal Tracking JS code installed.

Yet it's still not tracking. I can see it under Real Time Conversions, but it doesn't appear in Real Time Events nor Conversion Goals. What the heck could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I know you already posted an answer (and good for you for figuring out one solution). Would you be able to post a screenshot of your Goal Configuration? I'm curious to see what could be wrong with the original method (without GTM).

Answer (score 0):

After trying every code on the internets, I figured out how to simply set it up using Tag Manager! Obviously you have to have a GTM Account and paste the Tag Code on your website. Here's how to set it up:

- Set up a New Trigger called "Form Trigger"
- Choose "Custom Event"
- Fire On, copy and paste this: gtm.formSubmit
- Create Trigger

THEN ---

- Set up a New Tag called "Form Submission"
- Choose Product: Google Analytics
- Choose a Tag Type: Universal Analytics
- Enter Analytics Tracking ID
- Track Type: Event
- Category: Contact Form (or whatever, this will match the category name you set up in Goals in Analytics)
- Action: Submit (or whatever, this will match the action you set up in Goals in Analytics)
- You can add a Label and Value if you want, just make sure they match when setting up goals in Analytics. I just left them blank in both cases.
- Fire On: click "More" and select the "Form Trigger" trigger you previously created.
- Save Tag

Then just set up your Goals in your Analytics and test your form. In Reporting, I clicked on Real Time >> Events, filled out the form and BAM! I saw it right away and it recorded in Conversions instantly!

This was THEE only way I could get it to work. Works with sites with or without Yoast or whatever other SEO plugins. I hope someone finds this helpful, I tried EVERYTHING and this was the only way I could get it to work.

Cheers!